# ¿Existe en Android algo parecido al anchor link de HTML?

Tags: android

Estoy buscando la forma de navegar entre una larga lista de elementos (TextViews) en Android que se encuentran en la misma Activity (cada elemento dentro de un TableRow). Para que el usuario no tenga que hacer un largo scroll buscando la sección que le interesa, sería ideal tener botones en la parte superior que te lleven a la "altura" donde se encuentra el elemento. Básicamente necesito la funcionalidad de un botón a un link local (el id de un TextView) dentro de la misma Activity ¿Existe algo así?

**Actualización**

Gracias a la respuesta de @x4mp73r, este fue mi código final:

```
private final void focusOnView(){
    myScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, myTableRow.getTop());
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer uso de `ScrollView` con `smoothScroll` para poder dirigirte a un elemento en específico:

```
tuScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);

new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tuScrollView .smoothScrollTo(0, tuTextView.getBottom());
    }
});
```

Esto es usando *textviews*.

> **NOTA**
>
> Esta respuesta fue obtenida de [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18499953/scrolling-to-a-row-in-a-tablelayout-programatically). Si deseas obtener variedad de soluciones puedes visitar las siguientes preguntas similiares [Programmatically scroll to a specific position in an Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275227/im-trying-to-scroll-to-a-particular-portion-of-my-tablelayout-using-scrollto), [Scrolling to a row in a TableLayout Programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31275227/im-trying-to-scroll-to-a-particular-portion-of-my-tablelayout-using-scrollto), [Is there a way to programmatically scroll a scroll view to a specific edit text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831671/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-scroll-a-scroll-view-to-a-specific-edit-text)